# Private copies of books

Tags: copyright

Consider a book copyrighted by someone. Is it legal (in India? in USA?) to make an audio recording of the book and give copies privately to a handful interested people who ask for it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you do not have permission to make and distribute reproductions of the work, then it is illegal to make and distribute reproductions of the work.

[US copyright law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copyright_law_of_the_United_States)

[Indian copyright law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copyright_law_of_India)